# Accessibility regarding role="status"

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

I believe my question is probably overly simple, but I can't seem to find much information about how `role="status"` determines what content to announce. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated. Unfortunately, most resources point to this page that 404s https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#status

Comment: 1.1 docs: https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#status

Comment: Non-snapshot w3.org TR links (i.e., no date in the URL) aren’t stable. When a new spec is published, the URL paths might change. That’s why people should ideally link the stable URLs. You can go to https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/ and then find the link to the "Previous Recommendation", and then use the URL under "This version". -- The link in your question was probably from WAI-ARIA 1.0. This is the stable URL: https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-wai-aria-20140320/roles#status

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is? Do you ask how to provide the content for the `status` role? Or do you wonder what user-agents might do when a page contains a `status` role, or multiple?

Comment: I’m curious of both @unor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<div role="status">` is analagous to `<div aria-live="polite">` - [see reference](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Techniques/aria/ARIA22).

`<div role="alert">` is analagous to `<div aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">` - [see reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/ARIA19.html).

Live regions are a little tricky. To work correctly, they need to exist in the HTML at time of page-load, but they will only be announced when the content within the container changes. Updating the content within the container is usually accomplished via JavaScript.

When the `aria-live` attribute is set to an implicit value of `polite`, screen-readers should finish reading the current item before announcing the live region update.

When the `aria-live` attribute is set to an implicit value of `assertive`, screen-readers should interrupt the current flow of text to announce the live region update.

An implicit attribute of `aria-atomic="true"` means that the entire contents of the live region (not just the new or updated part) will be announced.

Terrill Thompson has a very good [ARIA Live Region Test Page](https://terrillthompson.com/tests/aria/live-scores.html) that demonstrates how live regions work in action.

Comment: Thank you for that! I noticed it seemed to be container based. So, any content that gets updated  within a container, it will be annnounced?

Comment: Yes, it should, BUT that really depends on the browser and screen-reader combination being used. I believe that all modern browsers should now support aria-live, and screen reader support has improved over the past few years, but there are probably still some combinations out there that don't work well. You may find this helpful: http://www.davidmacd.com/blog/test-aria-live-display-none.html

Comment: @Josh where did you find this information? To the best of my knowledge the role of status has an implicit `aria-live` value of `polite`, not `assertive`: https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Techniques/aria/ARIA22

Comment: Also, saying it is "analogous" to setting these two properties is misleading. It does implicitly set these attributes, but does more than that: it exists primarily to express that the content is advisory information.

Answer (score 0):

Can have a look at this.
https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/working-examples/aria-role-status-searchresults/

Every time there's a button click and value changes in the DOM.
`role="status"` makes it a point to announce those changes.

If you find a progress bar and add role status, it will announce every 4~5 seconds that the progress bar value is increasing.